# Regarding creating synchronization mechanism

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing a multithreaded Java class that runs the threads sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780123/testing-a-multithreaded-java-class-that-runs-the-threads-sequentially)

Please don't treat this below question as a duplicate one..!

I have developed a class that lets multi-threads to run sequentially, one at a time and in order.  All the application code between this class' claimAccess function and release Access function will be executed only in one thread at one time. All other threads will wait in the queue  until the previous thread completed.Please advise I want to test my class by writing a piece of code in main() method itself .

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AccessGate {
    protected boolean shouldWait = false;
    protected final List waitThreadQueue = new ArrayList();

    /**
     * For a thread to determine if it should wait. It it is, the thread will
     * wait until notified.
     * 
     */
    public void claimAccess() {
        final Thread thread = getWaitThread();
        if (thread != null) {
            // let the thread wait untill notified
            synchronized (thread) {
                try {
                    thread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * For a thread to determine if it should wait. It it is, the thread will be
     * put into the waitThreadQueue to wait.
     * 
     */
    private synchronized Thread getWaitThread() {
        Thread thread = null;
        if (shouldWait || !waitThreadQueue.isEmpty()) {
            thread = Thread.currentThread();
            waitThreadQueue.add(thread);
        }
        shouldWait = true;
        return thread;
    }

    /**
     * Release the thread in the first position of the waitThreadQueue.
     * 
     */
    public synchronized void releaseAccess() {
        if (waitThreadQueue.isEmpty()) {
            shouldWait = false;
        } else {
            shouldWait = true;
            // give the claimAccess function a little time to complete
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
            }

            // release the waiting thread
            final Thread thread = (Thread) waitThreadQueue.remove(0);
            synchronized (thread) {
                thread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my main method would be ..

```
public static void main (String args[])
{

}
```

please advise how I spawn thr threads in my my main method to test the above class..!!Please advise

Comment: consider using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`

Comment: @Hoaz Thanks a lot, Please post the complete code so that I can understand a more,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started...

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    AccessGate gate = new AccessGate();

    // create as many threads as you like
    Thread t1 = new MyThread(gate);
    Thread t2 = new MyThread(gate);

    // start all the threads you created
    t1.start();
    t2.start();        
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    AccessGate gate;

    public MyThread(AccessGate g) {
        gate = g;
    }

    public void run() {
        gate.claimAccess();
        // Do something or print something.
        // Could output several statements.
        // Why not do a sleep as well to see if other threads interrupt
        // this code section.
        gate.releaseAccess();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. This is a thread pool with only one thread executing tasks. Next task will start execution only after first task is finished:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<String> future1 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    String call() throws Exception {
        // my first task
    }
});
Future<String> future2 = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    String call() throws Exception {
        // my second task
    }
});
...
```

You can retrieve result of task execution via Future API, also it allows you to track status of each job.

Comment: Please advise me how I can convert the above code with executor, I will be really grateful to you if you could please post the complete code as I have done thanks in advance

Comment: you don't need any gates, just submit your tasks (Callable instances) to executor and they will be executed sequentially

Comment: Thanks a lot , but I can access this from main method through your suggested approach but I was trying to make the above class access gate by another approach completely through re entrant lock please advise for that

Comment: Not sure that I understand you correctly, can you explain me again? The code I have provided above already contains all synchronization blocks to execute several tasks one by one. All you need is to submit tasks, executor will take care about running them.

Comment: Well I want that the way I have made the access gate class as shown above ,is there any other way to make it by reentrant lock could you please post the complete code as I have made the access gate